# R.layout error in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am having a problem that R.layout is not defined can anyone help? As you can see I am not importing r.layout as been suggested in other answers to this obviously common problem.

Comment: try posting whole exception tree but reason obviously will related with resources

Comment: at first `clean-rebuild`

Comment: Already tried that no change

Comment: suggest something else

Answer (score 0):

clean and rebuild your project... this will solve your issue

Comment: already tried that no change

Comment: click on "invalidate caches and restart"

Comment: tried it already .. suggest some other fix .. getting R.layout error in main activity

Comment: show the whole log stack